# how to open a popup on hover event with clickable contant

Tags: javascript, html, popup, leaflet

i am currently working with leaflet.

and i am trying to create a popup with with clickable content.

now i found how i can bind popups on click event with content:

```
marker.on('click', function(e){
     marker.bindPopup("<div />").openPopup();
}
```

and i found out how to create the popup on hover:

```
marker.on('mouseover', function(e){
    e.target.bindPopup("<div />").openPopup();

    }});        

marker.on('mouseout', function(e){  
    e.target.closePopup();

}});
```

now what i cant seem to do is make the popup stay open in order for the user to click on links inside the popup.
i would appreciate any help.

Comment: You should have a 'close' button inside the popup, and remove the mouseout event handler.

Comment: @laruiss thank you for the idea. but i was looking for something along the lines of a popup that if you stay in its limits after the hover it wont close. this way after the over the user will be able to choose from the options in the popup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

one approach is this http://jsfiddle.net/cxZRM/98/
basically it's adding a timer to your setup and you only close the popup after an arbitrarily long time has passed so as to give the user some time to interact on your div.

```
marker.on('mouseover', function(e){
    e.target.bindPopup("dsdsdsdsd").openPopup();
    start = new Date().getTime();
  });        

marker.on('mouseout', function(e){  
    var end = new Date().getTime();
    var time = end - start;
    console.log('Execution time: ' + time);
    if(time > 700){
    e.target.closePopup();
    }
});
```

a better approach would be to use http://jsfiddle.net/AMsK9/
to determine your mouse position and keep the popup open while the mouse is still within an area around the popup.

Comment: thank you for the answer. the second option sounds batter but the size of the popup content is dynamic. do you have any idea how i can calculate the size of the pop for you second solution?

Comment: document.getElementById("mydiv").offsetWidth could help you

Comment: in the end i decided to use your first idea with an addition. the timer i used to keep the popup open until the hover event is triggered on the popup itself and then the timer is stooped.and i can interact with the popup.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, I wanted a different pop up for mouseover and another one for click, and the problem was that when I hovered out the click pop up closed, so what I did was adding a flag:

```
var modal = true;    
function onEachFeature(feature, Polygon) 
    {
        if (feature.properties && feature.properties.popupContent && feature.properties.modal) 
        { 
            Polygon.on('mouseover', function (e) {
              Polygon.bindPopup(feature.properties.popupContent);
              this.openPopup();
              modal = false;
            });
            Polygon.on('mouseout', function (e) {

                if(!modal)
                this.closePopup();
            });
            Polygon.on('click', function (e) {
                modal = true;
                Polygon.bindPopup(feature.properties.modal).openPopup();
            });

        }
    }
```