# hover of marker in leaflet

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I would like to ask if it is possible to hover not CLICKED the marker in the leaflet map

here is my code

**leaflet.js**

```
var map = L.map( 'map', {
  center: [20.0, 5.0],
  maxZoom: 16,
  minZoom: 2,
  zoom: 2
})

L.tileLayer( 'http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
   attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>',
   subdomains: ['a', 'b', 'c']
}).addTo( map )

var myURL = jQuery( 'script[src$="leaf-demo.js"]' ).attr( 'src' ).replace( 'leaf-demo.js', '' )

var myIcon = L.icon({
  iconUrl: myURL + 'images/pin24.png',
  iconRetinaUrl: myURL + 'images/pin48.png',
  iconSize: [29, 24],
  iconAnchor: [9, 21],
  popupAnchor: [0, -14]
})
```

here is where it shows the marker and the data in the leaflet map

```
var markers = [
["<b style='font-size:15pt;'> ROXAS CITY CHAPTER </b> <br> <i style='font-size:12pt;'> JUAN DELA CRUZ </i> <br>juan@yahoo.com", 11.58528,122.75111],
["<b style='font-size:15pt;'> MANILA CITY CHAPTER </b> <br> <i style='font-size:12pt;'> PEDRO DELA CRUZ </i> <br>pedro@gmail.com", 14.599512,120.984222],
["<b style='font-size:15pt;'> CANADA CHAPTER </b> <br> <i style='font-size:12pt;'> SIMON DELA CRUZ </i> <br>simon@gmail.com", 53.631611 ,-113.323975]
];
for ( var i=0; i < markers.length; i++ ){
  marker = L.marker ([markers[i][1], markers[i][2]], {icon: myIcon})
  .bindPopup(markers[i][0])

  .addTo( map );
}
```

here is a image for more understanding
[image]

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Add `mouseover` event on the marker and calling `openPopup()` in the handler like below:

```
marker = L.marker(...);

marker.on('mouseover',function(ev) {
  ev.target.openPopup();
});
```

or

```
marker.on('mouseover',function(ev) {
  marker.openPopup();
});
```

I have setup jsfiddle for the same : http://jsfiddle.net/74g6ts4r/

Comment: Note that this event doesn't seem to work flawlessly or I am missing something. Yes, the popup does appear once you hover the marker, but it then stays there and one needs to either activate another hover event somewhere or click to remove it. A hover event should not behave like that and should consider both the mouse entering AND exiting the specific location on the screen.

Answer (score 3):

You could use title attribute on [marker object](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#marker)

```
marker = L.marker ([markers[i][1], markers[i][2]], {icon: myIcon, title: "any text"})
```

Another approach could be firing openPopup with mouseover event:

```
    map.on('mouseover',function(ev) {
      ev.layer.openPopup()
    })
```

It was discussed on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26202789/how-to-open-a-popup-on-hover-event-with-clickable-contant)

Comment: does this hover?

Answer (score 2):

Can be achieved by

```
marker.on('mouseover',function() {
  marker.openPopup();
});
```

where marker is created via L.marker